# Django template 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8

Tags: python, django, templates, utf-8

I a template I am trying to link categories to a view that list all content of that category:

```
<div class="categories">
tags:
{% for c in post.categories.all %}</div>
<ul>
<a class="category" href="{% url "news.views.get_category" c %}">{{c}}</a> 
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

in urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^(?P<post_cat>[-\w]+)$', 'news.views.get_category'),
```

and in the views:

```
def get_category(request, post_cat):

    """News by Category listing."""
    posts = News.objects.get(categories=post_cat).order_by("-pub_date")
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)

    try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response("news/list-newss_by_category.html",
                              dict(posts=posts, user=request.user))
```

However I get this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(The category string is in Persian)

On the other hand when I just use

```
<div class="category">{{ c }}</div>
```

instead, the category string renders without issues.

So the problem is how to send the category item as parameter inside the {% url %} tag to the views.

I have tried different things all in vein. Appreciate your hints to resolve this.

---

**P.S**. Actually I **solved** the problem by using c.id in the template tag and adjusted urls.py and views.py accordingly. But still keep this question open. Hopefully someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `c.cat_slug` where `cat_slug` is the field that has the string that you want to appear in the URL. As in `{% url "news.views.get_category" c.cat_slug %}`

If you use: `{% url "news.views.get_category" c %}`, Python will call the method `__unicode__` from your model, and that's not what you want in this case.